# Exporting Highlighted Selections in Tensorboard Projector

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using google's tensorboard projector to visualize a corpus of documents. I am trying to curate the corpus, and would like to study the documents in clusters that appear during TSNE visualization. Is there a way to export the metadata of a group of documents that you select? [image]

I would like to study the metadata of everything that's highlighted in that image. Is this something that can be done with the projector, or with tensor board code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you go to "bookmarks" in the lower right corner, then press the "+" button, it will save the current state. You can then click the download icon to download the state file. From that, you should be able to parse out the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

select, edit label of selection, download

reload tensoboard, select, don't label, download

compare two downloads side by side in excel with filtering one of the columns for the label you set.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/820#issuecomment-352337256